# Table alignment and different column widths for it

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to align my middle table equal to the width of top and bottom one. Moreover I want to keep the width of "Description of Goods" column equal to the width of first column of the top table thereby adjusting the rest columns in the width left. The width of the column "per" can be just a little more than that of "Sl.No." column. All other columns width being equal. Here with attaching the screen shot:

[image]

```html
<table style="margin:0;padding:0" >
                            <tr>
                              <td style="width:5%;">Sl No.</td>
                              <td style="padding:5px; text-align: center; " > Description of Goods </td>
                              <td style="padding:5px; text-align: center; "> HSN/SAC</td>
                              <td style="padding:5px; text-align: center; "> Quantity</td>
                              <td style="padding:5px; text-align: center; "> Rate</td>
                              <td style="padding:5px; text-align: center; "> per</td>
                              <td style="padding:5px; text-align: center;"> Amount</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="width:7%; border-bottom:none;padding:5px 5px 0px 5px;">1</td>
                              <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:none;padding:5px 5px 0px 5px;"><b>'.$CompanyData->device_model.' </b></td>
                               <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:none;padding:5px 5px 0px 5px;"><b> </b></td>
                              <td style="width:12%;border-bottom:none;padding:5px 5px 0px 5px;"><b>'.$CompanyData->no_of_device_rent.' PCS</b></td>
                              <td style="width:12%;border-bottom:none;padding:5px 5px 0px 5px;"><b>'.number_format($CompanyData->unit_price,2).'</b></td>
                              <td style="width:6%;border-bottom:none;padding:5px 5px 0px 5px;"> PCS </td>
                              <td style="width:16%;border-bottom:none;padding:5px 5px 0px 5px;text-align:right;"><b> '.number_format($CompanyData->rent_amount,2).' </b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="width:7%;border-bottom:none;padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; "></td>
                              <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:none;padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; "><i> '.$vehicle_details.'</i></td>
                              <td class="mono" style="width:12%;border-bottom:none;padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; "></td>
                              <td style="width:12%;border-bottom:none;padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; " class="mono"></td>
                              <td style="width:6%;border-bottom:none;padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; " class="mono"></td>
                              <td style="width:16%;border-bottom:none;padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; " class="mono"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="width:7%; height:170px;vertical-align:top;padding: 0px 5px 5px; "></td>
                              <td style="padding:5px; text-align: right; padding-right: 2px; font-weight: bold; height:170px;vertical-align:top;padding: 0px 5px 5px; ">
                                  <i>'.$taxname.' @ 5%<br/>
                                '.$name_roundoff.' <br/>
                                Not Eligible for Input Tax Credit</i></td>
                              <td class="mono" style="width:12%; height:170px;vertical-align:top;padding: 0px 5px 5px; "></td>
                              <td class="mono" style="width:12%; height:170px;vertical-align:top;padding: 0px 5px 5px; "></td>
                              <td style="width:12%; height:170px;vertical-align:top;text-align:right;padding: 0px 5px 5px; "><b>5<br/>
                                <br/>
                                </b></td>
                              <td style="width:6%; height:170px;vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding: 0px 5px 5px; " class="mono"><b>%<br/>
                                <br/>
                                </b></td>
                              <td style="width:16%; height:170px;vertical-align:top;padding: 0px 5px 5px; text-align:right;" ><b>'.number_format($CompanyData->service_tax,2).'<br/>
                                '.$CompanyData->round_off.' <br/>
                                </b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="width:7%;padding:0;"></td>
                              <td style="padding:5px; text-align: right; padding-right: 2px; font-weight: bold;padding:0;"> Total </td>
                              <td style="padding:5px; text-align: right; padding-right: 2px; font-weight: bold;padding:0;">  </td>
                              <td style="width:12%;padding:0;"><b>'.$CompanyData->no_of_device_rent.' PCS</b></td>
                              <td style="width:12%;padding:0;"></td>
                              <td style="width:6%;padding:0;"><b style="font-size:14px;"></b></td>
                              <td style="width:16%;padding:0 5px 0 0;text-align:right;"><b style="font-size:14px;">Rs '.number_format($final_amount,2).'</b></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
```

Comment: Good luck maintaining this.

Comment: @user5014677 I am asking for help

Comment: I would suggest you to revisit your code before going any further cause that will be a big mess to work with later.

Comment: I want to align my middle table equal to the width of top and bottom one. The top and bottom one have a different width. Which one should be leading?

Comment: What is the width of you top and bottom column? why can you put everything in one table that have 3 rows, containing you three tables?

Comment: @Gerard no table should be leading. same width

Comment: The tables are to be adjusted such that this bill should be printable on A4 size paper.

Comment: @Gerard help me  please

Comment: I made a start in a separate snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am seeing one table in your code yet you are talking about three tables.
If there are different separate them and put them in different divs. Give them the same width, they are going to be equal

```
<div>
    <div> <table  style="width: 60%;"> put contents of table 1 </table></div>
    <div> <table  style="width: 60%;"> put contents of table 2 </table></div>
    <div> <table  style="width: 60%;"> put contents of table 3 </table></div>
</div>
```

Dont use specifically 60%, use the width that you want the tables to be.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is how I would do it. I've merged the first and second table. The borders help to visualize and can be removed later.

I also removed all the inline CSS. You should learn to work with classes and describe the CSS rules externally.

```css
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tod {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1px">
  <!-- 7 columns -->
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Despatched through</td>
    <td colspan="5">Destination</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tod" colspan="7">Terms of delivery</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sl No.</td>
    <td> Description of Goods </td>
    <td> HSN/SAC</td>
    <td> Quantity</td>
    <td> Rate</td>
    <td> per</td>
    <td> Amount</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><b>'.$CompanyData->device_model.' </b></td>
    <td><b> </b></td>
    <td><b>'.$CompanyData->no_of_device_rent.' PCS</b></td>
    <td><b>'.number_format($CompanyData->unit_price,2).'</b></td>
    <td> PCS </td>
    <td><b> '.number_format($CompanyData->rent_amount,2).' </b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><i> '.$vehicle_details.'</i></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><i>Not Eligible for Input Tax Credit</i></td>
    <td class="mono"></td>
    <td class="mono"></td>
    <td><b>5<br/><br/></b></td>
    <td class="mono"><b>%<br/><br/></b></td>
    <td><b>'.$CompanyData->round_off.' <br/></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td> Total </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td><b>'.$CompanyData->no_of_device_rent.' PCS</b></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><b></b></td>
    <td>Rs '.number_format($final_amount,2).'</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this is not what I want